# Aligning buttons and datetimepicker in one row/line

Tags: asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I want to have two datetime pickers and some buttons align in one row. I want the date time pickers on the row to be on the left and the buttons aligned on the right.

All of this I want in one row.

I have been messing around with this for some days now and cannot get them to be in one single row, they are all over the place.

The code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="height: 75px;">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="form-control">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepickerFrom' style="cursor: pointer; width: 200px;">
                        <input type="text" id="DateFrom" runat="server" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepickerTo' style="cursor: pointer; width: 200px;">
                        <input type="text" id="DateTo" runat="server" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <asp:Button ID="btnYesterday" runat="server" Text="Yesterday" class="btn btn-primary"
                        OnClick="btnYesterday_Click" Style="margin-top: 50px; width: 100px;" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnWeek" runat="server" Text="Week" class="btn btn-primary"
                        OnClick="btnWeek_Click" Style="margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 20px; width: 100px;" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnMonth" runat="server" Text="Month" class="btn btn-primary"
                        OnClick="btnMonth_Click" Style="margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 20px; width: 100px;" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As usual, thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the documentation for inline forms. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: Thanks for that, once I read it, it made sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally in bootstrap you would just put the class `form-inline` on your form element (or whatever container that contains your form elements). Your other inline styles may be hosing some of that up.  See this example:

See the fiddle here https://jsbin.com/juqereyazu/edit?html,output